# writting a binary in c++

Tags: c++, file

So i have this program that supposedly reads any file (e.g images, txt) and get its data and creates a new file with that same data. The problem is that i want the data in an array and not in a vector and when i copy that same data to char array, whenever i try to write those bits into a file it doesnt write the file properly.

So the question is how can i get the data from `std::ifstream input( "hello.txt", std::ios::binary );` and save it an `char array[]` so that i can write that data into a new file?

Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    FILE *newfile;
    std::ifstream input( "hello.txt", std::ios::binary );
    
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
        
    char arr[buffer.size()];
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), arr);

    int sdfd;
    sdfd = open("newhello.txt",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    write(sdfd,arr,strlen(arr)*sizeof(char));
    close(sdfd);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why does the data need to go in an array at all?  What is wrong with using a vector (which has the benefit of working)?  Have you tried using the array contents to re-create the vector, which (if successful) you know how to write to a new file?

Comment: because in a bigger project i need to pass the data into a tcp server that only accepts char arrays

Comment: `buffer.data()` gives you an `unsigned char*` pointer to the array managed by the vector, that you can pass to whatever function you are now passing `arr` to.

Comment: `strlen(arr)` doesn't return the same value as `buffer.size()`. It returns the offset of the first 0 (zero) byte, or exhibits undefined behavior if there is none such. `strlen` only makes sense when working with nul-terminated text strings; not for binary data.

Comment: It looks strange that to read a file, you use the C++ API `ifstream`, while to write you use the low-level, Unix only, C interface `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
(It basically uses a char*, but it's an array here. You probably can't have an array in the stack in this case)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("hello.txt", std::ios::binary);
    char* buffer;
    size_t len;  // if u don't want to delete the buffer
    if (input) {
        input.seekg(0, input.end);
        len = input.tellg();
        input.seekg(0, input.beg);

        buffer = new char[len];

        input.read(buffer, len);
        input.close();

        std::ofstream fileOut("newhello.txt");
        fileOut.write(buffer, len);
        fileOut.close();

        // delete[] buffer; u may delete the buffer or keep it for further use anywhere else
    }
}
```

This should probably solve your problem, remember to always have the length (`len` here) of the buffer if you don't want to delete it.
More [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/)

Comment: Even though this is what the OP asked for, I would not recommend this way. Managing memory manually is error prone. At worst I'd use `std::unique_ptr` with its array overload